# Get from a c++ server

Tags: c++, angular, rest, server

I have a client in Angular and my server is in C++. I know it's better to use node, but my boss wants me to use c++ :(

Right now, I use this [Server](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/C-Web-Server/tree/solution) from github.

When I do a get, it returns a text/plain.

Code in server:

```
void get_d20(int fd) {
   srand(time(NULL) + getpid());

   char response_body[8];
   sprintf(response_body, "%d", 5);

   send_response(fd, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "text/plain", response_body);
}

int send_response(int fd, char *header, char *content_type, char *body) {
   const int max_response_size = 65536;
   char response[max_response_size];

   // Get current time for the HTTP header
   time_t t1 = time(NULL);
   struct tm *ltime = localtime(&t1);

   // How many bytes in the body
   int content_length = strlen(body);

   int response_length = sprintf(response,
      "%s\n"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: %s\n"
      "Content-Length: %d\n"
      "Content-Type: %s\n"
      "Date: %s" // asctime adds its own newline
      "Connection: close\n"
      "\n" // End of HTTP header
      "%s",

      header,
      "*",
      content_length,
      content_type,
      asctime(ltime),
      body
   );

   // Send it all!
   int rv = send(fd, response, response_length, 0);

   if (rv < 0) 
      perror("send");

   return rv;
}
```

So, this is my code in client

```
public my_function(): void {
   let theResp;
   this.getServer().subscribe((resp) => {
      theResp = resp;
   });
   console.log('Return of get: ' + theResp);
}

 public getServer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3490/d20', {responseType: 'text'});
 }
```

In the console log, I have an undefined. I guess it's because the response type is an HTML file.

get_d20 returns a number between 0 to 20. How can I get the value in Angular?

Comment: I believe that line endings from a `HTTP` server should be "\r\n" not just "\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console.log()` outside subscribe callback is executed before the subscription is resolved put it inside the callback

```
  public my_function(): void {
       let theResp;
       this.getServer().subscribe((resp) => {
          theResp = resp;
     console.log('Return of get: ' + theResp);
       });

    }
```